# Why isn't rsync synchronizing this file?

Tags: linux, rsync

I have two versions of a file, each in a different directory:

```
$ dir foo{_test,}/bar.js
-rw-r--r-- 1 ikegami pg9999999 53721 Jun  9 15:11 foo/bar.js
-rw-r--r-- 1 ikegami pg9999999 53721 Jun  9 21:12 foo_test/bar.js

$ diff -u foo{_test,}/bar.js
--- foo_test/bar.js   2020-06-09 21:12:29.903536400 -0700
+++ foo/bar.js        2020-06-09 15:11:09.170603100 -0700
@@ -1801 +1801 @@
-   const build = "?build=1591762349";  // !!! Modified during publish !!!
+   const build = "?build=1586651406";  // !!! Modified during publish !!!
```

I try to use rsync to synchronize the directories:

```
$ rsync -vva foo{_test,} | grep bar.js
foo_test/bar.js is uptodate
```

Nothing changed.

```
$ dir foo{_test,}/bar.js
-rw-r--r-- 1 ikegami pg9999999 53721 Jun  9 15:11 foo/bar.js
-rw-r--r-- 1 ikegami pg9999999 53721 Jun  9 21:12 foo_test/bar.js

$ diff -u foo{_test,}/bar.js
--- foo_test/bar.js   2020-06-09 21:12:29.903536400 -0700
+++ foo/bar.js        2020-06-09 15:11:09.170603100 -0700
@@ -1801 +1801 @@
-   const build = "?build=1591762349";  // !!! Modified during publish !!!
+   const build = "?build=1586651406";  // !!! Modified during publish !!!
```

`rsync`(1) says

> *Rsync finds files that need to be transferred using a "quick check" algorithm (by default) that looks for files that have changed in size or in last-modified time.*

It seems to me the file should be updated because the files have different last-modified times. What am I missing?

(A word was replaced with `foo`, and a different word was replaced with `bar`. The original words consist entirely of lowercase ASCII letters. A 7-digit number was replaced with `9999999`.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your command:

```
$ rsync -vva foo_test foo
```

will create a new folder `foo_test` inside the `foo` folder.  Check if `foo/foo_test` folder exists!

This might seem unintuitive, but the `cp -a` command would do the same.

To avoid that, you can use:

```
$ rsync -vva foo_test/ foo
```

From the rsync man page:

> You can think of a trailing / on a source as meaning "copy the contents of this directory" as opposed to "copy the directory by name"